# CHECKDB problem - SQL files (mdfs,ldfs etc.) in Azure Files

Tags: sql-server, azure, dbcc-checkdb

Anybody out there using [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction) for SQL data and log file storage? I've got one SQL Server using an AF share in this manner and am having issues running `CHECKDB` on its databases. Has anyone out there used Azure Files for SQL stuff and, if so, have you run into the following problem?

When attempting to run `CHECKDB` on master:

> Msg 5030, Level 16, State 12, Line 1
> The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.
> Msg 7926, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Check statement aborted. The database could not be checked as a database snapshot could not be created and the database or table could not be locked.
> See Books Online for details of when this behavior is expected and what workarounds exist. Also see previous errors for more details.

When attempting to run `CHECKDB` on user database:

> DBCC CHECKDB will not check SQL Server catalog or Service Broker consistency because a database snapshot could not be created or because WITH TABLOCK was specified.

Comment: I would definitely recommend **not** using Azure Files for your database files - you're going to likely have a ton of performance issues in addition to weird one-offs like this.

Comment: LowlyDBA. Interesting why do you say that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Azure Files [has a lot of limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-scale-targets#file-share-and-file-scale-targets) that could be problematic.

Comment: Thanks just read through that but not sure what in there is of particular interest. I'm new to this side of SQL. Come from a dev / dev-DBA background. Anything you can point out there as specifically problematic would be much appreciated. I've already come to the conclusion that Azure Files is not great for SQL, but I need to justify that and understand why. 

What would you suggest as a better Azure alternative for SQL storage?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just [provision storage on your VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-storage-configuration) normally?

Comment: Just getting into this honestly. This is shared storage for a cluster. Inheriting duties and a server utilizing Azure Files. I will look into that though. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The documentation on this area is pretty good these days so I'd just spend some time reading through the Azure VM MSSQL sections and it should provide you with everything you need as far as best practices go.

Comment: Sweet thank you!

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If its < 2014 the issue could be the same as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2974455/dbcc-checkdb-behavior-when-the-sql-server-database-is-located-on-an-re).

Answer (score 0):

[DBCC CHECKDB uses a Database Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#internal-database-snapshot) by default.  Database Snapshots are an NTFS feature.  When storing the database on an SMB share, they aren't available.  Try specifying the TABLOCK option for DBCC CHECKDB.

And Azure Premium Files are intended to support SQL Server database file storage.   In addition to providing shared storage for clusters, they allow you to share storage resources among SQL VMs.  Before the release of Premium Files, Azure Files was not really recommended for SQL Server database storage.

When [Azure Shared Disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-shared-enable) are GA they may provide a better option for shared storage, but currently the only two options are Storage Spaces Direct, and Azure Premium Files.

Comment: Same problem for user databases with or without WITH TABLOCK. I get CHECKDB but it's not complete:

**DBCC CHECKDB will not check SQL Server catalog or Service Broker consistency because a database snapshot could not be created or because WITH TABLOCK was specified**

And on master I can't run CHECKDB at all - with or without WITH TABLOCK:

**The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.**

I've had to offload CHECKDB to a server not using AF. And I can't check master on another server so it's not getting checked at all. 

Any way around this?

Comment: You can always flip the database to read-only, or restore a backup to a local disk, perhaps the scratch and checkdb that.

Comment: Thanks but neither of those options works for master db. And even if either did work for master, I'm basically already doing the restore elsewhere and run CHECKDB option.  

Seems like if you can't run CHECKDB on master db and it's a pain on user databases, Azure Files is a no-go for SQL files. Right? I'd love to be wrong about this.

Comment: When you're storing the database on an SMB share, you're not really responsible for the storage solution.  CHECKDB really detects storage failures.

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying that it's redundant on my end as a DBA to be running that with Azure Files? Azure Files is robust enough where this will never be a problem? If not and there is corruption, would I get notified... somehow?

Comment: I would still run it on your user databases.

Comment: K but then I still have the same logistical problems and this affects RPO / RTO as I have to unload the db elsewhere and THEN run CHECKDB. 

Why would user databases be different from master as far as being in Azure Files? Would the type of corruption that might affect user dbs not be a risk for master in AF? 

Thanks.

Comment: Just rarely and with TABLOCK.

Comment: K but can you answer my question about master please? Why would it be different? That's the one I'm most worried about as it's the brains of the system and not so easy to restore.